# CodenameOne NetBeans IDE project right-click not working

Tags: codenameone

IDE: NetBeans IDE 8.0.2
NetBeans Plugin Version: 3.2.5
Desktop OS: CentOS 7

My problem is that my Codename1 main projects no longer bring up CN1 project options when I right-click them from within the NetBeans IDE. This prevents me from sending builds to the server, refreshing cn1libs files, and other options normally available from within the IDE by right-clicking a project.

Note that if I click project properties on my CN1 projects, I can see the usual codename1 options available there. But not when I right-click the project file, which was typical, and necessary to access certain functionality (sending builds, refreshing cn1libs, ...).

Note that this has been working well for a number of weeks. Also note that this MAY coincide with the update to plugin version 3.2.5 (Unclear).

Is there a way to reestablish the Codename1 project association? Or perhaps I need to revert to a previous plugin version (if so how)?

Steph

(Note that I also asked this question in forum before I noticed that tech questions should be asked here - so that's a dup)

Comment: I'm running CN1 3.2.5 on Netbeans 8.1 and 8.0.2 and it works perfectly on both.

Are you having this problem with a newly created projects? Are you able to Right-click on non-CN1 projects?

Comment: You can edit your answer if you're not allowed to post comment.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been resolved, although not 100% sure what caused it.  Here are some of the breadcrumbs:

I could right-click on any project, it just didn't show CN1 options - nor did it display the CN1 icon for CN1 projects.

Interesting though. When I created a new CN1 project in response to your questions (Diamond), not only did right-click work on it, but it started working on the other CN1 projects as well.

Thanks for the questions, as it helped to resolve my issue. Some sort of damaged configuration? The only remaining question is what in Netbeans or the plugin caused the damage in the first place?

Thanks for the help.  I'm back to the races!

Answer (score 0):

The possible reasons for this problem that I can think of are:

1. Low resolution hiding the additional menu item.
2. Missing or renamed `CodeNameOneBuildClient.jar`
3. Bug in the plugin

In case of the latter please check [the log](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqLogMessagesFile) from the NetBeans IDE and either attach it to the question or file an issue with the log.